# Add a value to a column of DASK data-frames imported using csv_read

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, dask

Suppose that five files are imported to the DASK using `csv_read`. To do this, I use this code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
data = dd.read_csv(final_file_list_msg, header = None)
```

Every file has ten columns. I want to add 1 to the first column of file 1, 2 to the first column of file 2, 3 to the first column of file 3, etc.

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? I got the first part but I'm kind of lost on the second.

Comment: @user32185 This is a simplified version of my problem. As I mentioned, for every specific file, I want to add a number to the series of first column. For the first column of the first CSV file, I add one to this column, for the second file, I add two to the first column of second file, etc.

Comment: Do you agree that this part ''Also, I my output file should have 10 columns and X rows which X is sum of the number of all rows of 10 files (every file has different number of rows/samples)" is not that clear?

Comment: In any case here you should use `delayed` as from dask there is no way to know which file in the partitions are you considering.

Comment: @user32185 Every file has different number of rows but same number of columns (10). So the final concatenated data-frame (`data`) has 10 columns and X rows ( X = number of rows of first file + number of rows of second file + ...)

Comment: it seems to me a redundant remark ;)

Comment: @user32185 I removed that part ;-) Can you describe more or maybe provide an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189025/discussion-between-user32185-and-user2991243).

Comment: Were you able to test my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume that you have several files following this scheme:

```
dummy/
├── file01.csv
├── file02.csv
├── file03.csv
```

First we create them via

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed

fldr = "dummy"

if not os.path.exists(fldr):
    os.mkdir(fldr)

for i in range(10):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3))
    df.to_csv("{}/file{:02}.csv".format(fldr,i+1),
              index=False)
```

The list of file created is `fns = sorted(os.listdir(fldr))`

Then we write a function that given the path `fn`:

- read the file
- takes the number XX in `fileXX.csv`
- insert `int(XX)` on the first column

That is

```
def addCol(fn):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(fldr, fn))
    first = int(fn.split(".")[0][-2:])
    df.insert(0, "first", first)
    return df
```

We wanted this fun to be `delayed` and we can achieve it using the decorator `@delayed` or wrapping the function with `delayed`. So to obtain the desired output we should fire (accordingly)

- `ddf = dd.from_delayed([addCol(fn) for fn in fns])`
- `ddf = dd.from_delayed([delayed(addCol)(fn) for fn in fns])`