# create a dataframe iteratively on pandas with identification column upon each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am trying to build a large dataframe (`main_df`), which eventually shall be created by appending the rows from multiple dataframes (`df_subdir`) in multiple subdirectories (`subdirs`), one level below a main directory (`main_dir`). In other words, I should:

1. change to (each of the) `subdirs`
2. fetch the data from the `df_subdir`
3. append the rows of `df_subdir` to `main_df`

this should be done for all `subdirs` in `main_dir`

Considering that my current working directory is already `main_dir` and all `df_subdirs` .xlsx dataframes (columns = `column1`, `column2` and `column3)` are directly located under `subdirs`, which is located exactly one level below `main_dir`, the code that I wrote so far does that, except for that **I want an extra column (`column4`) that uniquely identifies which `subdirs` the data (rows) came from**:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# initialise my dataframe
main_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])

# start the iteration    
for i in subdirs:
    os.chdir(f'{os.getcwd()}/{i}') # change to each of the subdirectories
    main_df = main_df.append(pd.read_excel('df_subdir.xlsx')) # append the data from df_subdir to main_df
```

Now considering that the names of my `subdirs` follow a pattern like `uniq-identifier_pattern_pattern`, I could extract the `uniq-identifier` with `os.getcwd().split('_')[0]`. These are the values I want to append to `column4` upon each iteration.

I have tried the following:

```
# initialise my dataframe with the extra column4
main_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4'])

for i in subdirs:
    os.chdir(f'{os.getcwd()}/{i}') # change to each of the subdirectories
    main_df['column4'] = os.getcwd().split('_')[0] # specify uniq-identifiers in column4
    main_df = main_df.append(pd.read_excel('name_of_df_subdir.xlsx'))
```

After doing this, `column4` has a single value, which is the `uniq-identifier` of the last `subdirs` iteration.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could you use **dask** for this.

To read all the file you can just run

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv("main_dir/*/*.csv")
```

where on the path `main_dir/*/*.csv` `main_dir` is the top directory, with  `*` between slashes we are considering all subdirectories and then `*.csv` stands for all csv in there.

For the last problem you should play with a custom function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54885202/4819376).