# Why dask doesnt execute in parallel

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

Could someone point out what I did wrong with following dask implementation, since it doesnt seems to use the multi cores.

[ Updated with reproducible code]

The code that **uses dask** :

```
bookingID = np.arange(1,10000)
book_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000))
def calculate_feature_stats(bookingID):
    curr_book_data = book_data
    row = list()
    row.append(bookingID)
    row.append(curr_book_data.min())
    row.append(curr_book_data.max())
    row.append(curr_book_data.std())
    row.append(curr_book_data.mean())

    return row


calculate_feature_stats = dask.delayed(calculate_feature_stats)


rows = []


for bookid in bookingID.tolist():
    row = calculate_feature_stats(bookid)
    rows.append(row)

  start = time.time()
  rows = dask.persist(*rows)
  end = time.time()
  print(end - start)  # Execution time = 16s in my machine
```

Code with normal implementation **without dask** :

```
bookingID = np.arange(1,10000)
book_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000))

def calculate_feature_stats_normal(bookingID):
    curr_book_data = book_data
    row = list()
    row.append(bookingID)
    row.append(curr_book_data.min())
    row.append(curr_book_data.max())
    row.append(curr_book_data.std())
    row.append(curr_book_data.mean())
   return row


rows = []
start = time.time()
for bookid in bookingID.tolist():
    row = calculate_feature_stats_normal(bookid)
    rows.append(row)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)  # Execution time = 4s in my machine
```

So, without dask actually faster, how is that possible?

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @rpanai added reproducible code above.

Comment: In general there is about 1ms overhead per task using dask see [doc](http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/efficiency.html#use-larger-tasks). So if you do the math with your 1e5 tasks, the 1e-3 seconds overhead and 8 cores you should have ~12.5 seconds of just overhead.

Comment: Then I can't understand which one is your actual problem. Do you need to calculate stats for different files? Or do you have a big df with a `bookingID` as column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

Extended comment. You should consider that using dask there is about 1ms overhead (see [doc](http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/efficiency.html#use-larger-tasks)) so if your computation is shorther than that then dask It isn't worth the trouble.

Going to your specific question I can think of two possible real world scenario:
1. A big dataframe with a column called `bookingID` and another `value`
2. A different file for every bookingID

In the second case you can play from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54885202/4819376) while for the first case you can proceed as following:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



# create dummy df
df = []
for i in range(10_000):
    df.append(pd.DataFrame({"id":i,
                            "value":np.random.rand(1000)}))
df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_parquet("df.parq")
```

### Pandas

```py
%%time
df = pd.read_parquet("df.parq")
out = df.groupby("id").agg({"value":{"min", "max", "std", "mean"}})
out.columns = [col[1] for col in out.columns]
out = out.reset_index(drop=True)

CPU times: user 1.65 s, sys: 316 ms, total: 1.96 s
Wall time: 1.08 s
```

### Dask

```py
%%time
df = dd.read_parquet("df.parq")
out = df.groupby("id").agg({"value":["min", "max", "std", "mean"]}).compute()
out.columns = [col[1] for col in out.columns]
out = out.reset_index(drop=True)

CPU times: user 4.94 s, sys: 427 ms, total: 5.36 s
Wall time: 3.94 s
```

### Final thoughts

In this situation dask starts to make sense if the `df` doesn't fit in memory.

Comment: I think you are right, when I added time.sleep(0.06) to the function, as my real function took around that time, dask execution is almost 8 times faster.